# Non-WWW gets ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID on a wildcard certificate

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, https, apache2, lets-encrypt

I have a wildcard certificate from Let's Encrypt for a website (*.storyfortwo.com).

When I go to 
http://storyfortwo.com or http://www.storyfortwo.com (no SSL) they are both redirected to https://www.storyfortwo.com and it loads properly.

On https://www.storyfortwo.com (with WWW) all is well too.

When I go to https://storyfortwo.com (without WWW), it gives me ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error.

I use Apache2 (2.4.29) with VirtualHost files:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName storyfortwo.com
    ServerAlias www.storyfortwo.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/storyfortwo.com/www

    # Redirect Requests to SSL
    Redirect permanent / https://www.storyfortwo.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName storyfortwo.com
        ServerAlias www.storyfortwo.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/storyfortwo.com/www    

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/storyfortwo.com.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/storyfortwo.com.access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/storyfortwo.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/storyfortwo.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/storyfortwo.com/chain.pem

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>

        <Directory /var/www/storyfortwo.com/www>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*.example.com` does not match `example.com`. You need a certificate with your bare domain as either the CN, which is common for wildcards, or as a SAN (Subject Alternative Name).

Comment: That is probably the issue. Can I redirect it with VirtualHost without getting the error?

Comment: Only from http. With https, https negotiation will take effect, and thus the error, before any redirection can occur.

Comment: @84104 would a potential "free" solution be to create a Let's Encrypt certificate for the bare example.com domain? [I'm assuming that (a) a reputable wildcard certificate has been purchased for *.example.com and (b) requests to example.com are redirected to *.example.com]

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the domain `storyfortwo.com` added to the certificate? Without it `storyfortwo.com` does not match the wildcard `*.storyfortwo.com` in the certificate.